# Визуализация классов Java в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, классы, диаграммы

Как визуализировать в Android Studio взаимосвязи классов Java в виде схемы или диаграммы?

Comment: Можно IDEA Pro использовать со встроенной функциональностью.

Answer (score 1):

> [CodeIris is a integrated visualization of your project source code in your IDE.](http://plugin.codeiris.com/what-is-it/)  (CodeIris - это интегрированная визуализация исходного кода вашего проекта в среде IDE)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плагин [CodeIris](http://plugin.codeiris.com/download/) визуализирует модули, пакеты и классы вашего проекта.

Особенности (свободный перевод, не реклама, мне пригодилось):

1. Синтаксический анализ исходного кода и java-кода
2. Визуализизация модулей и их зависимостей
3. Визуализизация классов и их зависимостей
4. Визуализизация пакетов и их классов
5. Фильтрация классов и пакетов
6. Выделение классов и пакетов
7. и т.д.

Установить в Android Studio можно так - Setting->Plugins->Browse Repositories->CodeIris